# How to figure out number of combinations given a sequence length and number of possible values per item

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

If you have 100 keys on a keyboard, and you are typing 5-letter long sequences, the question is how many unique sequences you can enter.

More generally, if you have `n` atomic values, and `m`-item long sequences, wondering how many `m-`item long sequences you can have.

Also, if you have 5-letter-long *max* sequences, and yet take into account the 1-, 2-, 3-, and 4-letter sequences as well, how many there are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) or multiplication principle.  If you have $a$ choices for the first event and for each of them $b$ choices for the second, you have $ab$ choices for the two events.  In your case you have $100$ choices for each event, so for two letter strings you would have $100^2$ choices.

Comment: I thought there would be factorial in there somewhere. Thanks.